# meteor blaze layout how to pass nested template with parameter when render

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template:

```
<template name="outerTemplateName">
...
    {{> Template.dynamic template=inner}}
...
</template>
```

However, the template that i want to render as inner template also have a dynamic template inside it:

```
<template name="innerTemplateName">
...
    {{> Template.dynamic template=anotherInner}}
...
</template>
```

Is it possible to use BlazeLayout.render() to achieve something like the template below?

```
<template name="outerTemplateName">
...
    {{> innerTemplateName anotherInner="anotherInnerTemplateName"}}
...
</template>
```

Comment: Please post your rendering code. I have solved this already but let me first see, how you call BlazeLayout.render() at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about passing Templates to other Templates but you can dynamically switch Templates by passing a String like this.

```
<template name="outerTemplate">
    {{> innerTemplate childTemplateName="templateA"}}
</template>

<template name="innerTemplate">
  {{#if showTemplate 'templateA' }}
    {{> templateA }}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showTemplate 'templateB' }}
    {{> templateB }}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="templateA">
    <h1>I am templateA</h1>
</template>

<template name="templateB">
  <h1>I am templateB</h1>
</template>
```

Template Helper

```
Template.innerTemplate.helpers({
    showTemplate : function (templateName) {
        return templateName === this.childTemplateName;
    }
});
```